How can I remove all yellow from PDF of old white paper with black text, free of charge?
Freely and effortlessly, how can I remove all the yellow from this PDF of a vintage book, with black text printed on white paper? I have just the PDF, not the physical book itself.


I followed the link, and it looks like that refers to another product, not Adobe's Acrobat software. "Studio Pro" is not an Acrobat version that I know of. there is an Acrobat Pro. I did some searching and found this: To adjust the contrast in Adobe Acrobat, you can use the Replace Document Colors option to change the color combination -- but I don't know if that will let you reduce yellow page backgrounds. Otherwise, Acrobat is document-oriented software, not an image editing program.

@user8356 Thanks. I improved my question.

It's probably best to use a raster image editor to do that. Desaturate the image, then apply a Brightness & Constrast adjustment.  Free software that can do it: GIMP, or Krita.

Looks like the PDF contains mostly scanned images of the pages of the book But it can have also other data, like

text layer created by optical text recognition software
bookmarks or table of contents which is linked
text pages as JP2 images which are much trickier than JPG.

JP2 is used because the format allows high compression of text and line drawings with far less compression artifacts than JPG.
Check this: Additional layers in "scanned" PDF
If you are lucky there's nothing that your raster image editor cannot convert to raster images. In that case you can import the whole PDF so that every page is in its own layer. If you cannot write scripts you must desaturate each layer and increase its contrast by applying curves.
As said already by others, GIMP is a good freeware candidate for opening your PDF. It has been several years able to open also JP2 files.
After correcting the color and contrast export as new PDF so that each layer is a page. I have tried this in GIMP only for 10 page PDFs, so I do not know do you have to do the job in shorter chunks to avoid freezing your computer. You can merge several PDFs to one with online tools. Check for example this: https://tools.pdf24.org/en/ Check also others, because they can contain more of what you want and I have missed its availability!
If there's a text layer or other useful data which cannot be let go, GIMP alone is not enough. In that case you can get a trial of a proper PDF editor. At least PDF-XChange Pro allows opening images (=scanned book pages) in GIMP, making there edits and replacing the image with the corrected version. The job must be done manually page by page, but then you can save the PDF without losing the searchable, selectable & copyable text layer, bookmarks nor the linked table of contents.
